# Text not changing when password and confirm password are the same KOTLIN android studio

Tags: java, kotlin

Code:

```
binding.confirmpasswordTextbox.doOnTextChanged { text, start, before, count ->

        cpasswordFiltered = binding.passwordTextbox.text == binding.confirmpasswordTextbox.text

        binding.textCPassAlert.text = if (cpasswordFiltered) "" else "As passwords não correspondem!"
    
    }
```

And before that I have this:

```
binding.passwordTextbox.doOnTextChanged { text, start, before, count ->

        passwordFiltered = !isValidPassword(text)

        binding.textPassAlert.text = if (passwordFiltered) "" else "A password deve conter 8+ caracteres, uma letra maiúscula, minúscula e um caracter especial!"

        cpasswordFiltered = binding.passwordTextbox.text == binding.confirmpasswordTextbox.text

        binding.textCPassAlert.text = if (cpasswordFiltered) "" else "As passwords não correspondem!"
    }
```

So what I can't understand is that it works for password filter, but not when confirming the password, are they different types of texts and that's why I can't get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by changing

```
 binding.passwordTextbox.text
```

to

```
 binding.passwordTextbox.text.toString()
```

Comment: Yeah the name `text` is a little confusing (trips me up now and then) but that returns an `Editable` object (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText#getText()) so like you've found, you need to convert the contents into a plain `String` if you want to compare them. (`Editable` is an interface, so the actual object could be anything - they can contain a lot more than just text content, like styling info)